# multiple conditions in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to apply multiple conditions in ruby on rails app like below:

```
  if !params[:parameters].blank? && params[:parameters] == "Designation" 
       puts "Hassan"
       @dynamicDesignation = ""
       @dynamicCompany = ""
       @dynamicFrom = ""
       @dynamicTo = ""
       @Profession = Profession.new( :UserID => current_user.id, :Designation => @dynamicDesignation, :Company => @dynamicCompany, :Job_From => @dynamicFrom, :Job_To => @dynamicTo)
       #@Profession = @Profession.save
    else
      puts "Ali"
       @dynamicDesignation = params[:parameters]
       @dynamicCompany = params[:parametersCompany]
       @dynamicFrom = params[:ParametersFromProf]
       @dynamicTo = params[:ParametersToProf]
       @Profession = Profession.new( :UserID => current_user.id, :Designation => @dynamicDesignation, :Company => @dynamicCompany, :Job_From => @dynamicFrom, :Job_To => @dynamicTo)
       #@Profession = @Profession.save
    end
      # redirect_to '/educations'
      render 'index'
  end
```

And parameters is dynamic control i.e below:

```
 var input = "<input name='parameters' id='field' type='text' value='Designation' style='text-align:center;' onblur='WaterMarkDesignation(this, event);' onfocus='WaterMarkDesignation(this, event);'/>";
                var input1 = "<input name='parametersCompany' id='field' type='text' value='Company' style='text-align:center;' onblur='WaterMarkCompany(this, event);' onfocus='WaterMarkCompany(this, event);'/>"
```

But its not going to the if condition, It only runs else condition, why. Kindly suggest me. Thanks

Comment: show us the value of variable params.

Comment: Likely reason for it skipping to `else` is that the `if` conditions aren't met -- can you show the data you're sending to the if?

Comment: I am not sending any value of in the if condition. Parameters is a text_field name and I want to check that if text_field text is not equal to blank and equal to "Designation" i.e placeholder. It not inserts "Designation" i.e placeholder in db, it inserts empty string in db.

Comment: You have to send at least "" if it is not "Designation" in parameters

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you're trying to ensure you don't get blank items saved into the DB, you should look at using [`nilify_blanks`](https://github.com/rubiety/nilify_blanks)

I would do this:

```
  #app/models/profession.rb
  Class Profession < ActiveRecord::Base
      nilify_blanks
  end

  #app/controllers/professions_controller.rb
  def create
      @Profession = Profession.new(profession_params)
      @Profession.save
      render 'index'
  end

 private

 def profession_params
     params.require(:profession).permit(:designation, :job_from, :job_to, :company).merge(userID: current_user.id)
 end
```

---

**Placeholder**

Secondly, you're trying to prevent a placeholder (`Designation`) from being sent, instead of using `value`, why don't use [`placeholder`](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder)

This will show the text you want, but will treat as blank unless it's been populated by the user:

```
<input name='parameters' id='field' type='text' placeholder='Designation' style='text-align:center;' onblur='WaterMarkDesignation(this, event);' onfocus='WaterMarkDesignation(this, event);'/>
```